# Stop highlighted text from autofilling sublime's goto anything search

Tags: sublimetext3

I use goto anything quite a bit, but mainly for searching for files. It goes a little something like this:

- cmd p, immediately start typing file name
- shit, there's a random string of junk at the beginning of my search
- backspace, backspace, backsp....
- type file name
- receive list of file choices that I wanted to begin with

Is there a setting I can set somewhere to make the behavior a little more sane for my use-case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's a default behavior. What plugins do you have installed? If you log the commands (`sublime.log_commands(True)` in the ST console), what do you see? I get `command: show_overlay {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true}`. If it's not that, a plugin may be binding to `super + p`. If that's the case, you may either remove the plugin, or create a user key binding with the proper command/arguments.

Comment: Awesome. Turns out super + p was running quick_goto_file. I changed it to the command you mentioned, and the world is good again :). Thank you stranger.